# How do you get a reference to your Scene Delegate (UIWindowSceneDelegate) as you would with your AppDelegate (UIApplicationDelegate)?

Tags: ios, swift, ios13, uiscene, uiscenedelegate

Prior to iOS 13, when AppDelegate was king, you could do (well you still can) `UIApplication.shared.delegate` to get a reference to your AppDelegate. But how do you get a reference to your UIWindowSceneDelegate that manages a single window scene in iOS 13? `UIWindowScene.shared.delegate` doesn't exist, obviously.